# Different Evaluation for ConvertFrom-Json

Tags: powershell

Why do the two following snippets produce different output?

```
Get-Content -Raw "test.json" | ConvertFrom-Json | %{
    Write-Output "MessageType: $($_.Messagetype)"
}
# this time make sure Get-Content and ConvertFrom-Json are evaluated completely, before the foreach
(Get-Content -Raw "test.json" | ConvertFrom-Json) | %{
    Write-Output "MessageType: $($_.Messagetype)"
}
```

Executing the snippets with the following json:

```
[
  {
    "MessageType": "A"
  },
  {
    "MessageType": "B"
  }
]
```

the first script produces

```
MessageType: A B
```

and the second the expected

```
MessageType: A
MessageType: B
```

So basically for the first snippet, the foreach gets a single element which is an array with 2 elements, while in the second snippet the foreach is called for every element.

I don't understand why forcing the evaluation completely changes the behavior here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell versions **up to v6.x, `ConvertFrom-Json`, unlike most other cmdlets, outputs arrays as *single objects***, instead of sending objects one by one through the pipeline.

Therefore, in your *first* command's `%` (`ForEach-Object`) script block, `$_` is the *entire array*, which, inside an expandable string (`"..."`) stringifies to a list of its elements separated by spaces by default.

By contrast, **enclosing a command in `()`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), turns it into an *expression*, and using an expression in a pipeline implicitly causes *enumeration* of the expression's result**, causing the objects to be sent one by one.

Note: Another notable side effect of using `()` is that an enclosed command's output is collected in full in memory.

Therefore, your *second* command's `%` (`ForEach-Object`) script block is invoked *twice*, with `$_` bound to a *single object* each.

Simplified examples:

```
# Sample JSON that is an array comprising 2 objects.
$json = '[
  {
    "MessageType": "A"
  },
  {
    "MessageType": "B"
  }
]'

# PS v6.x-: -> 1, because ConvertFrom-Json sent the array as a whole
$json | ConvertFrom-Json | Measure-Object | % Count

# -> 2, because using (...) resulted in enumeration
($json | ConvertFrom-Json) | Measure-Object | % Count
```

Comment: Oh so basically `ConvertFrom-Json` disables the usual PowerShell array unwrapping? Because I'd expect if the result of an expression was an array that the single elements would be piped into the foreach (i.e. `@(1,2) | Measure-Object | % Count` is 2 although we explicitly create an array). Is this simply due to the way that ConvertFrom-Json is implemented internally?

Comment: @Voo: Well, it doesn't so much disable it, it chooses to send an entire array as a single object to the pipeline, which in PowerShell code you can achieve with `Write-Output -NoEnumerate <array>`, or conveniently but obscurely, with `, <array>` (wrapping in an outer array). This is what _cmdlets_ and _functions_ can do. By contrast, whatever comes out of an _expression_ is _invariably_ enumerated. `1, 2 | ...` is the same as `@(1, 2) | ...` (and the `@(...)` is unnecessary to begin with).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, that clears things up. Personally I'd be happy if ConvertFrom-Json didn't have that behavior, but I guess there's probably a good reason for it.

Comment: @Voo: I too think that `ConvertFrom-Json` should enumerate; while there are down-sides (not being able to round-trip a single-element JSON array), it is ultimately less surprising; please see the link I've added in a footnote for a discussion on GitHub.